# Adding custom label on simple_form select and default option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, simple-form

I'm using the `simple_form` gem and I'm having a select field in my form for choosing a category. This is my code

```
= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, { promt: "-- Select Category --"}, class: "form-control"
```

1st. How can I add a label on my select box? I have tried adding this `:label => "Categories"` but throws a syntax error

2nd. The `{ promt: "-- Select Category --"}`, which supposed to be the default and the first option in the `option` tags, does not show at all. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way

```
<%= f.input :category_id, :collection => Category.all, :label_method => :name, :value_method => :id, :label => "Categories", :prompt => "-- Select Category --", class: "form-control" %>
```

And it looks like you had a typo with the word "prompt"

Comment: Thanks! is there a link available with a detailed documentation on how to generate form fields with simple form. I think the page on github (https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) doesn't have many details

Comment: you're welcome!  Hmm, well I looked at the documentation, and i do agree that it doesn't appear to have a very clear example...the info is buried in there though, under the "Collections" section.  This (old) Railscast could be helpful too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o0eVqNbapb0